# Redux & React: My reducer don't recognize action with setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, setinterval

I'm looking a way to create an action every second in my project with React and Redux.
In this way I can arrive until my action but my reducer don't recognize it.

```
class liftComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        setInterval(function(){
            handlerPosition()
        }, 1000);
    }



    render() {}

} 

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    currentLevel: state
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    handlerPosition: (currentLevel) => dispatch(handlerPosition),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(liftComponent);
```

Comment: Is this snippet pulled from a project of yours somewhere?  It looks like some parts are missing.  It may also help if you post the actions and reducer(s).

Comment: What does the rest of your code look like? Action producer, reducer, etc... From the looks of it also doesn not seem like you pass `currentLevel` to the handlerPosition call in the setInterval callback, and it also looks like it is not passed through to the dispatched action. Can you share a minimal, verifiable, and complete code example that reproduces your issue?

Comment: Drew has the right of it. `handlerPosition` is doing nothing except dispatching itself (as a function) once when called.

Comment: @JosephSikorski you can find here: https://github.com/marcopestrin/algorithm-lift

Comment: @DrewReese you can find the rest of the code here: https://github.com/marcopestrin/algorithm-lift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most of the way there, at least in your code on Github.  [`mapDispatchToProps`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch) injects the created functions as props, so access them like `this.props.callUp(i)` in a class component.

```
componentDidMount(){
    // Probably should do something better with intervalId.
    // setState()?
    this.intervalId = setInterval(
        () => {
            this.props.callUp({thisLevel: 10000000});
            // or this.props.handlerPosition() or whatever.
        },
        1000
    );
}
```

Comment: When I saw the github link I thought "how did he get that, did he search github for the code, is there a code search like image search", then I saw OP's comment. :)

Comment: No problem!  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using a functional component with hooks. 
I think the problem is in the mapDispatchToProps function.

You have to change this:

`handlerPosition: (currentLevel) => dispatch(handlerPosition)`

to this:

`handlerPosition: () => dispatch(handlerPosition())`

I hope my solution fits to your problem.